# Can adapter provide content to NumberPicker?

Tags: android

```
valuepicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.valuepicker);
        String[] city = {"city1","city2","city3","city3","city4","city4"};
        valuepicker.setDisplayedValues(city);
        valuepicker.setMinValue(0);
        valuepicker.setMaxValue(city.length - 1);
        valuepicker.setValue(4);
```

can city provide by adapter?
and how？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NumberPicker` extends `LinearLayout` so you can't use an `Adapter` with it, but you can give it an array of Strings to display with [`setDisplayedValues`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues(java.lang.String[])).